# using selenium to get all WhatsApp chats names

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I've been trying to do it for about 2 weeks with no success - how can I get all the chats names I have on WhatsApp using selenium?
I tried everything, and didn't find any similar question on internet,
Help will be appreciated

Here is the part of the code that is supposed to do it but it works just for the first 20-30 and then stops:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'PATH')
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
input("scan qr")

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=PHONE_NUMBER&text=&source=&data=')
time.sleep(13)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/header/div[2]/div/div/span').click()
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/span/div/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div').click()
time.sleep(2)

counter = 1
while True:
    group = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/span/div/ \
                                         div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[' + str(counter) + ']/ \
                                         div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span')
    name = group.get_attribute('title')
    print(name)
    counter += 1
```

The error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Roy/PycharmProjects/WhatsApp Bot/test.py", line 34, in <module>
    div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/span')
  File "C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/span/div/                                          div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[23]/
```

Comment: Please add some part of your code, show some of your efforts. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with **"and then stops"** ? Did you get an error or something?

Comment: I added code and error. Please have a look

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/span/div/span/div/                                          div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[23]/          <- this is the error you have got, the thing is that your driver could not locate an element, i would recommend to use explicit / implicit wait